# Convert and set projection from h5 file

Tags: python, coordinate-system, gdal, c++, c

I want to save georeferences readed from input data to output data.
I don't want use copy georeferences because input data is in .h5 format and georeferences was read from metadata.

I use GDAL and C but i accept program in C++ and python

Correct georeferences is EPSG 2180
https://epsg.io/2180
PROJ.4:

```
+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=19 +k=0.9993 +x_0=500000 +y_0=-5300000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
```

In file i can read:

```
+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0.0 +lon_0=19.0 +k=0.9993 +x_0=500000.00 +y_0=-5300000.00 +ellps=WGS84
```

It is possible to use:

```
OSRSetWellKnownGeogCS( hSRS, "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0.0 +lon_0=19.0 +k=0.9993 +x_0=500000.00 +y_0=-5300000.00 +ellps=WGS84" );
```

This system does not have UTM zone but if I don't use this it not working:

```
OSRSetUTM( hSRS, 11, TRUE );
```

I want to save this georeferences:

```
+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0.0 +lon_0=19.0 +k=0.9993 +x_0=500000.00 +y_0=-5300000.00 +ellps=WGS84
```

Convert to this:

```
PROJCS["ETRS89 / Poland CS92",GEOGCS["ETRS89",DATUM["European_Terrestrial_Reference_System_1989",SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6258"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4258"]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",19],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9993],PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],PARAMETER["false_northing",-5300000],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","2180"]]
```

To file using:

```
GDALSetProjection( hDstDS, georeferences);
```

Is it possible or how to convert it?

GDAL Info:

```
bash-4.2$ gdalinfo 201804010000_acc0010_grs.h5
Driver: HDF5/Hierarchical Data Format Release 5
Files: 201804010000_acc0010_grs.h5
Size is 512, 512
Metadata:
  dataset00_data0_data_CLASS=IMAGE
  dataset00_data0_data_IMAGE_VERSION=1.2
  dataset00_data0_what_quantity=ACRR
  dataset00_quality0_data_CLASS=IMAGE
  dataset00_quality0_data_IMAGE_VERSION=1.2
  dataset00_quality0_what_quantity=QIND
  dataset00_what_prodpar=000
  how_software=grs
  how_source=GAU+ GAU_QI+ RAD+ RAD_QI+ SAT+ SAT_QI+
  how_source_gau=376
  how_source_rad=BRZ- GDA- LEG- PAS- POZ- RAM- RZE- SWI- czbrd- czska- skjav+ skkoj+ skkub+ sklaz+ UKLL+ gedrs- gepro- geros- ltlau- ltvln-
  how_sw_args=compr=ZLIB, int=OK, grs=QSP, grs_qi=AVG_W
  how_sw_version=2.0
  what_acclength=10
  what_date=20180401
  what_nodata=-999
  what_object=COMP
  what_product=SURF
  what_time=000000
  what_type=GRS
  what_version=RainDIM 1.1
  where_projdef=+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0.0 +lon_0=19.0 +k=0.9993 +x_0=500000.00 +y_0=-5300000.00 +ellps=WGS84
  where_xllcorner=50000
  where_xscale=1000
  where_xsize=900
  where_yllcorner=30000
  where_yscale=1000
  where_ysize=800
Subdatasets:
  SUBDATASET_1_NAME=HDF5:"201804010000_acc0010_grs.h5"://dataset00/data0/data
  SUBDATASET_1_DESC=[800x900] //dataset00/data0/data (64-bit floating-point)
  SUBDATASET_2_NAME=HDF5:"201804010000_acc0010_grs.h5"://dataset00/quality0/data
  SUBDATASET_2_DESC=[800x900] //dataset00/quality0/data (64-bit floating-point)
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0,  512.0)
Upper Right (  512.0,    0.0)
Lower Right (  512.0,  512.0)
Center      (  256.0,  256.0)
```

Comment: H5 files can vary with how things are stored. Can you share the original file?

Comment: @snowman2 - I add the gdalinfo from file. Sorry i can't share this file.